# Java regex: match character based on previous character

Tags: java, regex

How to match a closing quote (single or double) depending on opening quote used?

For now I have:

```
key.*?=["'].*?["']
```

But unfortunately the closing quote is not dependent on the opening one and it won't work for the following example:

```
key="foo'bar"
```

I could created 2 sub but I assume that it isn't optimal:

```
key.*?=(".*?"|'.*?')
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried capturing the first quote in a group and using a back-reference at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back reference `\n` (e.g. `\1` - for the first capturing group, `\2` for the second)

So your example would look like:

```
key.*?=(["']).*?\1
```